# Show that $f(x)=3x+5$ is Riemann integrable on $[1,3]$, and calculate integral value by use partitions

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $f(x)=3x+5$ is Riemann integrable on $[1,3]$, and calculate integral value by use partitions.

My answer:
The function $f(x)$ is integrable because every continuous function is integrable, and this function is continuous on $[1,3]$.

As for integral value i think the partition i have to use it is:

$P={1, a+(b-a)/n}$

$P={1, 1+ 2/n}$

True or false? And what about $n$?

Comment: By using the partition $$P[1,3]=\left\{1,1+\frac{2}{n},1+\frac{4}{n},\ldots,1+\frac{2k}{n},\ldots, 3\right\}$$ we get, since $f$ is increasing
$$L(P,f)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(1+2(k-1)/n)(2/n)\qquad\text{and}\qquad U(P,f)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(1+2k/n)(2/n)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the partition $$P[1,3]=\left\{1,1+\frac{2}{n},1+\frac{4}{n},\ldots,1+\frac{2k}{n},\ldots, 3\right\}$$ we get, since $f$ is increasing
\begin{align*}
L(P,f)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(1+\frac{2(k-1)}{n}\right)\left(\frac{2}n\right)\\[4pt]
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(8+\frac{6(k-1)}n\right)\frac{2}n\\[4pt]
&=\frac{4}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(4n+3k-3)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{4}{n^2}\left(4n^2+\frac{3n(n+1)}{2}-3n\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2(11n^2-3n)}{n^2}
\end{align*}
Similarly, we have
\begin{align*}
U(P,f)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(1+\frac{2k}{n}\right)\left(\frac{2}n\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2(11n^2+3n)}{n^2}
\end{align*}
Now, the norm of the partition $P$ is $\left\|P\right\|=\frac{2}{n}$, so as it tends to zero, $n\to\infty$, so
$$L(f,P)\to 22\qquad\text{ as well }\qquad U(f,P)\to 22$$